# Low lm-sensors voltages on Gigabyte GA-H87-D3H

Tags: hardware, lm-sensors

I'm seeing the following readings from lmsensors

```
$ sensors
it8728-isa-0a30
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:          24.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in1:           2.03 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in2:           2.06 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in3:           1.99 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in4:          12.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in5:           1.79 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in6:           1.49 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
3VSB:          3.36 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +6.12 V)
Vbat:          3.34 V  
...
```

The board is [Gigabyte GA-H87-D3H](https://www.gigabyte.com/sg/Motherboard/GA-H87-D3H-rev-1x).

What is concerning is the in0 and in4 readings which shows in millivolts.
Does anyone know details about the source of the in0-in6 voltages?
Do they matter? As what seemed like a possible short circuit or open circuit in the vin0 and vin4 sensors.

If you happen to run the same board what do the sensors voltage readings look like?
I'm wondering if it would be resolved by changing the power supply?
Other things like CPU temperatures are pretty normal around room temperatures, fan speeds is low.

Comment: All values are within the stated specs. Are you having a problem with the computer? If not, don't worry about it.

Comment: thanks, initially my pc refuse to to boot and beeps repeatedly in POST, i did some web searches and noted that that could be a problem of power supply failure. However, after several attempts my pc actually boots successfully. it is a rather new power supply and this seemed unlikely. Hence, i'm starting to suspect the low voltages being the POST problems, possibly shorts?

Comment: Count the number of POST beeps, and then refer to the User Manual to tell you what the problem is. Good chance it's memory. Maybe the DIMMs need to be re-seated, or you've got a bad DIMM. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: just an update i tried memtester, apparently that ran ok and has no issues
https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-test-the-ram-on-linux

then from google searches i stumbled into this
https://www.pcspecialist.co.uk/forums/threads/my-gigabyte-motherboard-beeps.60980
which apparently says "Continuous short beep ：Power supply unit failed"
for now it is still millivolts but by sheer luck i've been able to boot, finger crossed